# How to get data from parent class (not extend)

Tags: php

Here is sample code:

```
namespace myApp

class app
{
    private $pdo = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->user=new User();
        $this->user->getPDO();
    }
}

class User
{
    public function getPDO() {
        //get PDO from app class
    }
}
```

How from User class get `$pdo` from app class?? 
Can't use extends because of construct in app class.
I don't want to declare independent classes (app and User) and than use global to communicate with each other.

EDIT:
is this solution ok?
namespace myApp

```
class app
{
    public $pdo = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->user=new User($this);
        $this->user->getPDO();
    }
}

class User
{
    private $app=null;

    public function __construct($app) {
        $this->app=$app;
    }
    public function getPDO() {
        return $this->app->pdo;
    }
}
```

Comment: `new User($this->pdo)`?

Comment: If `$pdo` is a **private** attribut of the `app` class, why the `User` one's should access to it?

Comment: @Fractaliste Why not? It's called [abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)). `private` variables let you hide the internals of a class while `public` methods let you manipulate those private variables in a manner that you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a good candidate for dependency injection.

You can declare the constructor for your Userclass for example like

```
__constuct($pdo) {
  $this->pdo = $pdo;
}
```

And then create User like

```
$this->user = new User($this->pdo)
```

An added advantage of this is that when you want to test your code you can easily mock pdo and test user without doing actual database actions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare 2 functions in your app class like this:

Then you have acces through this functions to the pdo variable

```
public function setPDO($pdo) {
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
}

public function getPDO() {
    return $this->pdo;
}
```